# How do I manage my repos when I have client and server code in one repo?

Tags: git

I have a **project** folder and inside the **project** I have **client** and **server** folders. I want to initialize this as one repo so I do **git init** in the **project** folder and **push** to GitHub. 
How do I go about **client** and **server** folders? Do I need to **git init** in these folders as well? How do I do **commit** and **push** inside these folders? If I'm working on **server** I probably don't want to **commit** and **push** on **project** folder level. What would be the most convenient workflow?

Comment: You've got it right.  Your repo covers all the children directories.  If you look at your commit either with `git show` or on Github, you'll see you've committed your whole repo.

Comment: if I'm working i.e in `server/` folder do I have to go directory up to `project/` and then do commit? or I can do it being in `server/` folder? What's the difference?

Comment: Everything from your top-level dir is in git's view.  You can be in any directory when you commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I go about client and server folders? Do I need to git init in
>   these folders as well?

No. Since you have initialize a git repo using `git init` in a parent folder, automatically all the subfolders (children) will be added to the repository and can be controlled from parent folder.

> How do I do commit and push inside these folders?

You can do any git command when you are in the parent folder or inside those sub directories.

> If I'm working on server I probably don't want to commit and push on
>   project folder level. What would be the most convenient workflow?

1. Do a `git status` from parent folder and check the files which needs to be staged.
2. Use `git add` to stage necessary files from *server* folder (having prefixed with `server/` and then `git commit` and `git push` respectively.

You can run above commands within `server` folder as well.